# Drupal setup RSS feed import- how do I map?

Tags: drupal-7, rss, drupal-modules

(using Drupal 7 Feeds module, XPathParser, Feeds Tamper- all latest versions)

I want an RSS feed to create nodes of a particular content type. In the content type I have a field_title, field_start_date, and field_guid fields I want to bring in with the rss, and a description field I want some users to be able to fill in later, after the nodes are created.

How do I map these fields?

On the mapping section of the feed importer page, it doesn't know what fields I'm bringing in yet because I haven't defined the source of the feed. There is no choice for the date or guid.

I need to add more options in the souce pulldown, but I don't know how to do that. I can only make field_title get populated. It seems Drupal would need to know the xml I'm bringing in before I get to set up the mapping.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: If you read the feeds documentation, it has every thing explained

Comment: In the docs it says:
"HTTP Fetcher: Download content from a Web site. If you have opted to attach the Importer to "Use standalone form" (Basic setting, above), then you will be able to enter the Web address (URL) in the form. If you have optioned to attach the Importer to a Content type, the URL will be entered there."

Comment: I see no place to enter a url for the feed anywhere in the feeds importer config pages, whether I use stand-alone form or content type. (or maybe they're referring to the add/node form?) And since I want to create nodes with the feed, it seems I should be using the attach to content type

Or can I use stand-alone and just have the entity selection on the node processor page, be the content type name?

I'm just not getting it.

Comment: You do not add url while mapping & configuring. You  will see a content type -- feeds. This is where you have to add the url to import data from

Comment: If I add my feeds url there, then all the nodes that are created are of the feeds item content type and not my own content type. The goal is to have some fields filled in by the feed and backend users can fill in the rest.

Comment: I've read the docs pretty well and am now using XPath Parser and I can name the xml elements to match them with the fields of my content type but only the title and body come across and the nodes are of the feeds item content type.

If the guid does as well, I can't tell, but other fields are not getting created. This happens when stand alone form is set in the importer basic settings, but if I select my content type to have the feed create nodes, no nodes get created.

Comment: First you need to select the file and feeds will read the header. Then you can map the fields with those headers.